# When I dismiss a UIImagePicker in a full-scren app, the status bar shows and moves everything down 20px

Tags: xcode4.2, statusbar, ios5

I have set-up a `UIImagePickerViewController` in a full screen app (Status bar initially hidden). But when it comes to testing it on the simulator, the status bar shows when the `modalViewController` is dismissed. What's the problem?

Any help appreciated!

Seb

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the image on http://vickiwenderlich.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Basic_iOS_Stats_iPhone.jpg

Status bar is 20 pixels high.

iPhone screen resolution is width=320 and height 480, and when it is retina display it is 640 by 960. If you take a photo in the low resolution, you will see that it is 720x960. In the camera roll, the image you is actually cropped.

You can try to resize the image which is really not easy.

You can try to dismiss the status bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a solution to this, it's advice about a bug in UIKit.  I've found the same situation and discovered the key moment when the bad behaviour happens.

To duplicate the bug, first you need to present a UIImagePicker controller using presentModalViewController, and the image picker has sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum.
It also helps, to visually see the bug, to adjust the frame of the UIImagePicker's view prior to presenting it, so you can see the top of the screen.

Then place a breakpoint on your call to dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: or dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: and step over it, watch the statusbar get drawn instantly (assuming your UIImagePicker is NOT full screen, within your full-screen app) and check [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden] before and after.

It changes state, but does not change if using sourceType = ..Camera or ...PhotoLibrary.

So I'd advise using PhotoLibrary instead of ...SavedPhotosAlbum.